# Matrix calculus - matrix derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus

I don't understand how given

- $X$ is $m \times n$
- $\Sigma$ is positive definite
- $f=\theta^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^T\theta$

How is $df/d\theta = 2X\Sigma^{-1}X^T\theta$.

Comment: Compute $f(\theta+h)-f(\theta)$ and discard $\|h\|^2$ terms.

Comment: $(\theta+h)^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^T(\theta+h)-\theta^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^T\theta = h^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^T\theta+h^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^Th+\theta^TX(\Sigma^{-1})^TX^Th=h^TQ\theta+h^TQh+\theta^TQh=2h^TQ\theta+h^TQh$

Comment: The middle term is bounded by $\|h\|$ the remaining terms (which are linear in $h$) can be grouped together (use $x^T y = y^T x$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is how this works. Call $A = X (\Sigma)^{-T} X^T$ and note that $A^T=A$. Now we write the quadratic form $Q$ as

$$Q = \theta A \theta^T = \theta_i A_{ij}  \theta_j = A_{ij} \theta_i \theta_j$$

Where [summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Statement_of_convention) is implied. Now, take the derivative with respect to $\theta_k$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \theta_k} &= A_{ij}  ( \frac{\partial \theta_i}{\partial \theta_k} \theta_j +  \theta_i \frac{\partial \theta_j}{\partial \theta_k} ) \\
&= A_{ij} ( \delta_{ik} \theta_j + \theta_i \delta_{jk} ) \\
&= A_{kj} \theta_j + A_{ik} \theta_i \\
&= A_{kj} \theta_j + A_{jk} \theta_j \\
&= 2 A_{kj} \theta_j \\
\end{align}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \theta}
&= 2 A\theta \\
&= 2 X (\Sigma)^{-T} X^T \theta
\end{align}$$

I may give you some intuition to remember this matrix identity once and for all. Consider the quadratic form $Q$ as a simple single variable function of $\theta$. So $Q=A\theta^2$ and then take the derivative to get $2A\theta$. However, this is just for remembering and not actually presents what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to "see" this without opening the looking at the indexes?

Comment: Yes, that was the point of mu comment above...